# A simple PDE solution question

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, numerical-modelling

I need to ask a question about partial derivatives.
I want to solve this equation (steady state, one dimensional continuity equation):
$$\frac{\partial (\rho u)}{\partial z}=0$$
which is equivalent to:
$$\rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+u\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}=0$$
and discretized by means of finite differences:
$$\rho_i\frac{(u_i-u_{i-1})}{\delta z}+u_i\frac{(\rho_i-\rho_{i-1})}{\delta z}=0$$
along with initial conditions like:
$$z=0 \quad \rho_i=\rho_0 \quad , \quad u_i=u_0$$

***My questions are:*** Does this equation has one unique solution? I mean one could increase $u$ and decrease $\rho$ (or the other way around) and have infinite solutions right?
In this case this equation can describe the conservation of the quantity $(\rho u)$. What about the conservation or $u$ or $\rho$?
If I could calculate the $\rho$ (density) variable through lets say an equation of state (like $PV=nRT$) which would be variable in $z$ direction can i rewrite the first equation like:
$$\rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$$
$$\rho_i\frac{(u_i-u_{i-1})}{\delta z}=0$$
which do have one unique solution.

Just to let you know of my intention, I eventually want to solve a set of PDEs:
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
+\frac{\partial (\rho u)}{\partial z}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial C_i}{\partial t}
+\frac{\partial (u C_i)}{\partial z}=Reactionrate$$
$$\rho=MW_{mean}\frac{P}{RgT}, MW_{mean}=\sum^{N_{comp}}_{i=1}(Y_i*mw_i), Y_i=\frac{C_i}{\sum^{N_{comp}}_{i=1}{C_i}}$$

Comment: In general, it's better to apply the finite difference scheme ***without*** using the product rule.  You will find that the resulting method is more stable and preserves continuity.

Comment: Paul, thank you for your reply. I have read about the difference of conservative and non conservative form [see link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70496/conservation-vs-non-conservation-forms-of-conservation-equations). The think is that if I treat the quantity ρ*u like one variable then in the case of dynamic balance I would have another one (ρ). Is n't that correct? I would need more equations than the ones that i have now. Maybe one to correlate ρ & u?

Comment: Also, please [refer to this link](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/dynamic-mass-balance-in-plug-flow-reactor) for a more detail explanation of my problem.

Comment: I think you should put your follow-up questions into a question of itself.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth. You mean like a whole new question? or like an answer to this question?

Comment: A whole new question. Updating old questions is confusing because the answers no longer seem to fit the question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your interest. I will delete the update from here and make a new one hoping for an answer.

Comment: I have posted a new question [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/22004/pde-discretization-via-finite-difference-sheme-question) which is a follow up question but didnt have any luck until now.. Should I try asking tha same thing but in a different way?

Answer (score 5):

The equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\rho u)=0$ only has a unique solution for the product $\rho u$ (namely a constant), but not for each factor separately. You need a different equation to tease them apart.

In your context, the equation describes the conservation of momentum. You will need a separate equation for the conservation of mass, which is going to have a term $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\rho$. Together, these two equations are going to uniquely define both velocity and density.